# Is it possible to purge an entire directory with the Akamai CCU REST API using a wildcard?

Tags: akamai

I think the title says it all. We have a site that uses a URL parts to specify locale, category, product, and product variation. For example:

```
/[country-code]/[category-slug]/[product-slug]/[variation-id]
```

As we support about 10 different locales, and some products have up to 30 variations, if we change a category, we can sometimes be trying to purge up to 1500 urls.

Is it possible using the Akamai CCU REST API to add a wildcard value, say for the country code, or variation id?

```
/*/[category-slug]/[product-slug]/*
```

I have seen some mentions of wildcards around but I'm not sure if they're supported by the API

Comment: Is there any new around this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I never found a solution to this so I don't think it's possible unfortunately. I ended up purging each URL individually.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I figured out this would probably be your answer. Unfortunately I don't have a way to know each url (image that contains the size in the url in endless permutations) :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. When you go to CCU, click on "Refresh by Directory & File Extension". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a purge by CPCode.

I've just written a getting started guide for the CCU API:

```
https://community.akamai.com/community/developer/blog/2015/08/19/getting-started-with-the-v2-open-ccu-api?sr=stream
```

The only difference for your case is that you'll want to allow purge by CPCode, and set up a CPCode for the file areas you want to purge at once.

Answer (score 0):

(9 years too late but in case anyone else needs this answer)

No it is not possible to use wildcards with the Akamai ccu fast purge API.
What you are looking for is the [Enhanced Content Control Utility (ECCU) API](https://techdocs.akamai.com/eccu/reference/api).

This API allows to purge content from Akamai by directory path, which is great if you don't know all the urls of your content, reach the message size limit, or encounter throttling due to the number of urls to purge.
Note however that unlike the fast purge API, purging using this API may take up to 40min as opposed to the 5 seconds with the fast purge.